# Setting Yii viewPath conditionally in controller action

Tags: php, yii

I need to set viewPath dynamically based on some conditions in a controller action. I am aware of a method by placing a method called getViewPath() in your controller as below:

```
public function getViewPath() {
  $controllername = $this->getId();
  $newPath = "application.views.extra";
  $newPath = YiiBase::getPathOfAlias($newPath);
    return $newPath;
}
```

But as i said earlier i need to set viewPath based on a condition. like this:

```
public function actionView($section) {
   switch ($section) {
     case 'yoga':
       $viewpath = 'yoga';
     break;

      case 'cycling':
        $viewpath = 'cycling';
      break;
   }

    // Now this should render from either:
    1.  protected/views/yoga/  
    2.  protected/views/cycling/
     $this->render('view');
}
```

Controller class has getViewPath() but not setViewPath() and viewPath property is also readonly.

Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: This is doable, but why exactly do you need to do it? Why not simply `$this->render($section.'/view')` and placing the directories inside your controller's default `viewPath`?

Comment: Since i haven't found the exact answer to my question to complete customize the view path as per need, i believe your solution is the only choice. Willem has also provided a similar solution below. Thanks for the comment. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `//` in a render path defaults to `protected/views/`, so you can do the following:

```
public function actionView($section) {
   switch ($section) {
     case 'yoga':
       $viewpath = '//yoga/';
     break;

      case 'cycling':
        $viewpath = '//cycling/';
      break;
   }

    // Now this should render from either:
    //1.  protected/views/yoga/  
    //2.  protected/views/cycling/
     $this->render($viewpath.'view');
}
```

Comment: Since i haven't found the exact answer to my question to complete customize the view path as per need, i believe your solution is the only choice. Jon  has also provided a similar solution in the comment above. Thanks. Appreciate it.